# How Do sequence numbers affect sliding window protocol with fixed window size?

Tags: protocols, communication, theory

I've been going through, trying to learn this protocol from a book, except at this point they seem to shy away from it, they express that the sequence bit is the number of frames one can send and receive but apart from that they dont approach it any more.

I want to know how it affects the protocol with a fixed window size.
Does a sequence bit of 3 with a window size of 4 mean that the sender cannot send more than 3 frames at any one time?

Or does it mean that the frames are numbered in the sequence of: 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2

As you can see, i'm quite confused, but that for any help! its much appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try wikipedia-> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sliding_window_protocol

"Sliding window protocols are used where reliable in-order delivery of packets is required." The ordering of the packets is defined using the "sequence numbers" which are attached on every packet. In two way communications both sides agree to a window size before transmitting any packets containing actual data. That window size could be fixed or dynamically changed.

1. So for a client to client communication for example, lets say the window size is 10 packets. Relying on the sequence numbers this means it is initially from packet with sequence 0 to packet with sequence 10.
2. After the agreement takes place and the data transmission begins, the client A will start sending the first packets with seq numbers: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.
3. Client A will stop sending packets when the window size (10) was reached according to the sequence numbers.
4. Client B replies with an acknowledgment(ACK) that it has received the packets 1,2,3,4.
5. That means the window moves from 0-10 to 5-14. The offset 10 remains the same in sliding window protocols with fixed size.
6. Therefore client A is able to sent the next 4 packets which are 11,12,13,14.

In general, as long as the client A has data to sent, it will keep sending until the window size is reached. Then it waits for ACKs from the other side, before it can continue sending again.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence number indicates how the frames that are being sent are numbered.

For example, if the frames are numbered from 0-7, then it is a 3-bit sequence number.
If the frames are numbered from 0-15 then it is a 4-bit sequence number.